# Python: copy a set in order?

Tags: python

In Python, is it possible to copy a set in the same order as the original? For example, rather than:

```
>>> s = {'r','g','b'}
>>> t = {i for i in s}
>>> t
set(['r', 'b', 'g'])
>>>
```

Can `t` be set to:

```
{'r','g','b'}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a list then?

Comment: No. Sets aren't ordered. If you want order you need another data structure - a `list` or and `OrderedSet`.

Comment: @thefourtheye: I don't want duplicates.

Comment: @sweeneyrod Yes, I saw that. Just wondering if there might be an easy way to make a copy.

Comment: @gjdanis Sets *have no order*, so you can’t *copy* the original order simply because there wasn’t an order to begin with.

Comment: @poke That's true--and so weird! When you make a set, then, how is the position of the elements in the set determined?

Comment: @gjdanis They don’t have a position. When you print it, it just returns the elements in an arbitrary order that has no further meaning but is entirely implementation specific. Imagine a bag with items, and you simply draw elements one-by-one from it and that’s the order for sets. It’s non-predicatable, without any meaning and solely for the purpose of accessing all elements.

Comment: @poke Is there a reason the designers of Python decided to do things this way? I thought the main advantage (among others) of using a `set` over a `list` was to avoid duplicates?

Comment: @gjdanis But [sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) simply don’t have an order.

Comment: @poke Yes, but is there an advantage to not ordering?

Comment: @gjdanis Several. Most and foremost, it’s way more efficient. If you have an order, then *that* order is part of the item’s property, making it harder to identify items with the same value (but different positions). Sets are implemented using hash tables, so they have a O(1) access; lists cannot work that and have a O(N) access instead. If there was a data structure that would support everything (efficient access, uniqueness, order) then that would be incredible cool, but it’s simply not possible; so you have to decide what you need and what you can pass on.

Comment: @poke Couldn't you allow O(1) access for a list? Isn't appending and popping the last element off the list O(1)? https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @gjdanis List access by index is constant time; but getting an item by value or checking if a value exists within the list (which would be required if you want to allow only distinct elements) is linear time as you need to check every element. Btw. if you have further questions or want to discuss this more, please join [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) and let us continue there.

Answer (score 1):

Try manipulating the `OrderedDict` from `collections`, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> x = ['a','b','c','b','c']
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x))
['a', 'b', 'c']
```